# Unable to generate HTML Report

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I use the below mentioned command to generate HTML Report in jmeter.

```
D:\JmeterTool\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin>jmeter -n 
  -t "D:\JmeterTool\coreApi's.jmx" 
  -l  D:\JmeterTool\JmeterReports\16012019.csv 
  -e -o D:\JmeterTool\HTMLReports
```

Whenever I run this command I get an error:

Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
   Results file:D:\JmeterTool\JmeterReports\16012019.csv is not empty

although this CSV file is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [-f or --forceDeleteResultFile](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61956) flag to override results file

> force delete existing results files before start the test

```
 jmeter -n  -t "D:\JmeterTool\coreApi's.jmx"  -f -l D:\JmeterTool\JmeterReports\16012019.csv -e -o D:\JmeterTool\HTMLReports
```

Comment: this command is not allowing me to delete data from CSV.



Command : 
D:\JmeterTool\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin> jmeter -n -t "D:\JmeterTool\JmeterScripts\coreApi's.jmx" -f -l D:\JmeterTool\JmeterReports\17012019.csv
Creating summariser <summary>
Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not delete results file D:\JmeterTool\JmeterReports\17012019.csv(canRead:true, canWrite:true)

Comment: @NitishPal you are probably updating/viewing/locking the file, can you delete it manually?

Comment: Yes manual delete is there but i wants to find the reason for same.